# Symfony 2.8 - Circular reference error at the end of composer install

Tags: symfony, composer-php

I need help, I've just take care of new project so I follow the process to install in my local and at the end of the install I got a circular reference error with *Symfony 2.8*.

To install the project in my local I run the command:

`composer install`

after enter, all information needed to install I got this error:

```
Circular reference detected for service 'knp_menu.matcher', path: 'knp_menu.matcher -> sonata.admin.menu.matcher.voter.children -> knp_menu.matcher'.
```

I don't know how to fix my problem. Could you help me please.

Comment: Did the project work before?  Was there a composer.lock file?  PHP version differences between the working installation and your new installation?

Comment: The projet works before
They was a composer.lock, that I delete to execute the install.
For the php version I didn't know, right now I used 7.2

Comment: I've just tested with php 5.4 and I've the same issue :/

Comment: You should keep the composer.lock to ensure you get the same dependency versions.  You can always upgrade later.  I have to admit that I don't really think that a dependency issue would cause a circular reference.

Comment: I get back the composer.lock and re install the project. But I've always this issue :/

Answer (score 1):

i found the solution.
I've to comment these line in this file:

> /vendor/sonata-project/admin-bundle/Resources/config/menu.xml

```
<service id="sonata.admin.menu.matcher.voter.children" class="Sonata\AdminBundle\Menu\Matcher\Voter\ChildrenVoter">                                                    
        <argument type="service" id="knp_menu.matcher"/>                              
        <tag name="knp_menu.voter"/>
</service>
```

Comment: So now you will want to search your code for sonata.admin.menu.matcher.voter.children and see if it is being used.  If it is then you will get an error when that particular code runs.  Very strange that it used to work.

Answer (score 0):

I share with you the composer.json. I think the problem come from deprecated version of different lib. But I can identify witch one

```
{
"name": "tarik/sonatacms",
"license": "proprietary",
"type": "project",
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "": "src/",
        "SymfonyStandard\\": "app/SymfonyStandard/"
    }
},
"require": {
    "php": ">=7.0.3",
    "symfony/symfony": "2.8.*",
    "doctrine/orm": "^2.4.8",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.4",
    "symfony/assetic-bundle": "~2.3",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "~2.3",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "~2.4",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "~4.0",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^3.0.2",
    "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
"sonata-project/core-bundle": "3.10.*",
    "sonata-project/admin-bundle": "3.0.*",
    "sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle": "3.0.*",
    "sonata-project/user-bundle": "3.0.*",
    "sonata-project/datagrid-bundle": "2.3.1",
    "sonata-project/easy-extends-bundle": "^2.1",
    "sonata-project/intl-bundle": "^2.2",
    "sonata-project/classification-bundle": "3.0.0",
    "sonata-project/media-bundle": "3.0.0",

    "jms/serializer-bundle": "^1.0",
    "stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle": "^1.2",
    "tilleuls/ckeditor-sonata-media-bundle": "1.0.5",
    "egeloen/ckeditor-bundle": "4.0.*",
    "ibrows/sonata-translation-bundle" : "1.0.*",

    "sonata-project/block-bundle": "3.10.*",
    "sonata-project/cache-bundle": "^2.2",
    "sonata-project/seo-bundle": "^2.0",
    "sonata-project/notification-bundle": "3.0.*",

    "symfony-cmf/routing-bundle": "~1.1",

    "sonata-project/page-bundle": "3.0.*",
    "sonata-project/formatter-bundle": "3.2.1",

    "videlalvaro/php-amqplib": "^2.6",
    "liip/monitor-bundle": "^2.3",
    "liip/imagine-bundle": "^1.3",

    "sonata-project/news-bundle": "3.10.* || 3.0.*",

    "symfony-cmf/core-bundle": "^1.2",
    "sonata-project/timeline-bundle": "3.0.*",
    "sonata-project/translation-bundle": "2.0.2",
    "hwi/oauth-bundle": "^0.4.0",
    "beberlei/DoctrineExtensions": "^1.0",
    "friendsofsymfony/elastica-bundle": "^3.1",
    "knplabs/knp-snappy-bundle": "^1.4",
    "h4cc/wkhtmltopdf-amd64": "0.12.x",
    "h4cc/wkhtmltopdf-i386": "0.12.x",
    "friendsofsymfony/comment-bundle": "^2.0",
    "sonata-project/comment-bundle": "3.0.0",
    "knplabs/knp-paginator-bundle": "2.4.2",
    "kptive/payment-sips-bundle": "^1.0",
    "symfony/var-dumper": "^3.1",
    "herzult/forum-bundle": "dev-master",
    "codeconsortium/ccdn-forum-bundle": "dev-master"
},
"require-dev": {
    "sensio/generator-bundle": "~2.3",
    "doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle": "^2.3",
    "hautelook/alice-bundle": "^1.2"
},
"scripts": {
    "post-root-package-install": [
        "SymfonyStandard\\Composer::hookRootPackageInstall"
    ],
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::removeSymfonyStandardFiles",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::prepareDeploymentTarget"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::removeSymfonyStandardFiles",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::prepareDeploymentTarget"
    ]
},
"config": {
    "bin-dir": "bin"
},
"extra": {
    "symfony-app-dir": "app",
    "symfony-web-dir": "web",
    "symfony-assets-install": "relative",
    "incenteev-parameters": {
        "file": "app/config/parameters.yml"
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Glad you got it working.  Or at least got past the error.  As a rule you should update your question when you want to add additional information.  There is a not very obvious Edit link in the lower left corner.